# ReSharper Wants To "Optimize" My Code

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Does the following...

```
    SomeType _someProperty;
    public SomeType SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            if (_someProperty == null)
                _someProperty = new SomeType();
            return _someProperty;
        }
    }
```

...have the same functionality as the following?

```
    SomeType _someProperty;
    public SomeType SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty ?? (_someProperty = new SomeType()); }
    }
```

According to ReSharper they do. And if so, can someone please explain the syntax of the second block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are the same functionality.

`??` is the [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  The operator returns the value before the operator if not null, or the value after the operator if the preceding value is null.

In this case, by wrapping the second part of the expression in params, you are assigning a new object to the `_requiredFieldValidator` backing field before returning it if `__requiredFieldValidator` is null.

If you did not have the parentheses, you would not assign before returning, which results in the following compile-error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer

The parentheses guarantee that the assignment expression is evaluated correctly.

Comment: So is the 2nd block more "efficient" then the first one? They're kind of doing the same thing.

Comment: Not at all.  They will compile to the exact same Intermediary Language.  The second syntax block is simply more "compact".  It's simply syntactic sugar for the first.

Comment: What is the significance of the parenthesis surrounding `_someProperty = new SomeType()` in the 2nd block?

Comment: @m-albert updated my answer to reflect your last comment.

Comment: So the parenthesis simply specify the order of operations. Got it. :-)

Comment: Exactly :).  The compiler can't infer what you are trying to do otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are the same.

`??` is the [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  If the operand on the left hand side of `??` is not null it will use that thing, otherwise it will use the operand on the right hand side.

In your case it will return _requiredFieldValidator if it is already initialized, otherwise it will initialize it first then return it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are the same. `??` is the *Null Coalescence Operator*, which checks the first operand against `null`, and if it's `null` then returns/runs the second operand.

The second code block says "Return `_someProperty` if it's not `null`. However, if it *is* `null`, then set `_someProperty = new SomeType()` and return that."

Answer (score 4):

I think most confusion here comes not from ?? operator. Just many people do not know that [Assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) in C# returns right-hand value as it's result.